# Return array from a function using malloc

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management

I'm trying to read text line by line, after looking at some examples, I decided to use the `malloc` method, however I keep getting error

```
error: subscript of pointer to function type
       'void *(unsigned long)'"
```

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *readFile(char filename[])
{
    char line[100];
    char *list = malloc(100); //causes error...
    int i = 0;

    FILE        *file = fopen(filename,  "r");  

    while (fgets (line, sizeof line, file)!= NULL)
    {
        list[i] = line;
        i++;
    }
    return list;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char *p = readFile(argv[1]);    
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
   {
        printf("%s", list[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Basically I have an assignment to examine a text file that has 4 columns, I'm trying to store each line into an array, and then use `strtok` to break each line into 4 tokens. Then I would store each token into a separate array (so that each column is an array). Then I would go through each array and do the required operations. However, I'm really stuck on this step.

Comment: `list[i] = line;` is not what you want. Your compiler should also warn you about that.

Comment: @Kerrek - Stack Overflow welcomes enthusiast programmers. Perhaps [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users) would apply here?

Comment: @jww: I *do* welcome new, enthusiast users. Seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **readFile(char filename[]){
    char line[100];
    char **list = malloc(100*sizeof(char*));//for 100 lines
    int i = 0;

    FILE *file = fopen(filename,  "r");  

    while (fgets (line, sizeof line, file)!= NULL && i < 100){
        list[i] = malloc(strlen(line) + 1);
        strcpy(list[i], line);
        ++i;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return list;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char **list = readFile(argv[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        printf("%s", list[i]);
    }
    //deallcate list[i], list
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I haven't seen anything with `**` in my course yet (assume another type of pointer?), I'll have a look why that is. Ohh... I was putting pointer into list as well, and thats why you used strcpy... thanks...

How do I reward you for helping me? I can't upvote you(need 15 reputation)

Comment: @caha11 `char**` is pointer to pointer to `char`. if char *list[i] then `list[n] = line` : Does not mean the copy of the contents by simply copying same pointer of `line`.

Comment: Yeah I understand man, thanks a lot.

I literally spent a long time on no progress, and this helps a lot. I'm new to this website, how do I give you rep? or what can I do to reward you for assisting me

Comment: @caha11 Please accept it by clicking the V mark if the problem was solved.